# TypeError: "function" takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I would like to applicate the function bellow, which is a responsible to augment each image and transform it :

```
def color_distortion(image, s=1.0):
    # image is a tensor with value range in [0, 1].
    # s is the strength of color distortion.

    def color_jitter(x):
        # one can also shuffle the order of following augmentations
        # each time they are applied.
        x = tf.image.random_brightness(x, max_delta=0.8 * s)
        x = tf.image.random_contrast(x, lower=1 - 0.8 * s, upper=1 + 0.8 * s)
        x = tf.image.random_saturation(x, lower=1 - 0.8 * s, upper=1 + 0.8 * s)
        x = tf.image.random_hue(x, max_delta=0.2 * s)
        x = tf.clip_by_value(x, 0, 1)
        return x

    def color_drop(x):
        x = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x)
        x = tf.tile(x, [1, 1, 3])
        return x

    rand_ = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0, maxval=1)
    # randomly apply transformation with probability p.
    if rand_ < 0.8:
        image = color_jitter(image)

    rand_ = tf.random.uniform(shape=(), minval=0, maxval=1)
    if rand_ < 0.2:
        image = color_drop(image)
    return image

def distort_simclr(image):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    v1 = color_distortion(image / 255.)
    v2 = color_distortion(image / 255.)
    return v1, v2
```

on my dataset imported like bellow

```
training_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(path, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes = ([2,224,224,3],[2,2]))
```

So I write this :

```
training_set = training_set.map(distort_simclr, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

I find this:

```
tf__distort_simclr() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is an example of my dataset :

```
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
gen = img_gen.flow_from_directory('/train/',(224, 224),'rgb', batch_size = 2)
training_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda : gen, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32), output_shapes = ([2,224,224,3],[2,2]))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code (code + data), so that your error can be reproduced? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok, I edit my code, I think it is more clear now..

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not possible to reproduce your error. Try to adjust your code together with some data, so that anyone can run it to encounter the same error as you do.

Comment: Can you please add the code where you define your img_gen (I assume ImageDataGenerator())? Also your "flow_from_directory" can not be executed for others, since only you have the directory with the data. Someone, without your local files can still not run your code.

Comment: my folder contain images of dog and cat (2 classes)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your `training_set` has 2 elements but you are passing just one element to function `distort_simclr`.

Below is a simple code to reproduce your error -

**Error code -**

```
import itertools
import tensorflow as tf

def gen():
  for i in itertools.count(1):
    yield (i, [1] * i)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     gen,
     (tf.int64, tf.int64),
     (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None])))

print(dataset)

def doNothing(i):
    return i

dataset = dataset.map(doNothing)

list(dataset.take(3).as_numpy_iterator())
```

**Output -**

```
<FlatMapDataset shapes: ((), (None,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-27a58aace75c> in <module>()
     15     return i
     16 
---> 17 dataset = dataset.map(doNothing)
     18 
     19 list(dataset.take(3).as_numpy_iterator())

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    256       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    257         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 258           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    259         else:
    260           raise

TypeError: in user code:


    TypeError: tf__doNothing() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

To fix the error pass both the elements to the function.

**Fixed Code -**

```
import itertools
import tensorflow as tf

def gen():
  for i in itertools.count(1):
    yield (i, [1] * i)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
     gen,
     (tf.int64, tf.int64),
     (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None])))

print(dataset)

def doNothing(i,j):
    return i,j

dataset = dataset.map(doNothing)

list(dataset.take(3).as_numpy_iterator())
```

**Output -**

```
<FlatMapDataset shapes: ((), (None,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int64)>
[(1, array([1])), (2, array([1, 1])), (3, array([1, 1, 1]))]
```